# Calculating the integral $\int(a^2-x^2)^n dx$

Tags: recurrence-relations, indefinite-integrals

> Show that $$\int(a^2-x^2)^n dx=\dfrac{x(a^2-x^2)^n}{2n+1}+\dfrac{2na^2}{2n+1}\int(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}dx$$

My try (integrating by parts): $$\int(a^2-x^2)^n dx=x(a^2-x^2)^n-\int xn(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}(-2x)dx\\ =x(a^2-x^2)^n-\dfrac{n}{n}\int nx(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}d(a^2-x^2)\\ =x(a^2-x^2)^n-\int xd(a^2-x^2)^n=x(a^2-x^2)^n-x(a^2-x^2)^n+\int (a^2-x^2)^n dx,$$ so we basically arrive at $0=0$, which is true, but not very useful. Any ideas?

Some thoughts that may (or may not) be useful. In order to get the denominator in the RHS which is $2n+1$, we actually have to find an expression for $I_n=\int (a^2-x^2)^n dx$ in which we must have $I_n$, namely $(-2nI_n)$ (as $I_n+2nI_n=(1+2n)I_n$), and $I_{n-1}$ as well.

P.S.  I am not yet familiar with the approach that uses substitution for solving integrals, so I'd rather integrate by parts on this occasion (as I think it would probably work).

Comment: Suggestion - try an appropriate trigonometric substitution. (Sadly, the general form involves some hypergeometric functions: see entry 78 here: https://www.integral-table.com/downloads/integral-table.pdf)

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I am not yet familiar with the approach that uses substitution for solving integrals, so I'd rather integrate by parts.

Comment: First of all, fix the notation. $x$ inside the integrals has nothing to do with $x$ in the fraction on the RHS, In other words, what are the bounds of integration?

Comment: @user58697, first of all, who were you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{align}I_n=\int(a^2-x^2)^n dx
&=x(a^2-x^2)^n-\int xn(a^2-x^2)^{n-1}(-2x)dx\\
&=x(a^2-x^2)^n-2n\int (a^2-x^2)^{n-1}(a^2-x^2-a^2)\\
&=x(a^2-x^2)^n-2n I_n+2na^2 I_{n-1}
\end{align}$

Collect $I_n$'s together and finish.

Comment: Where did dx go in the third integral you wrote?

Comment: @MathStudent: I am used to writing $\int f(x) dx$ as $\int f(x)$ so I skip that sometimes.

Comment: Nice idea, though! Thank you!

Comment: It is the same, but converting to the trigonometry with $x = a sin \theta$ and integrating by parts works.